# Rust custom panic_fmt lead to found duplicate lang item `panic_fmt` the lang item is first defined in crate `core`

Tags: rust, embedded, standard-library, rust-crates, nightly-build

On an embedded project with Rust, I'm currently facing the following issue when I try to implement my own panic handler.

To give you some context, I'm currently building my project with rust nightly version.
The code is here :

```
#![no_std] //Disable standard lib
#![no_main]
#![feature(lang_items)]

#[lang = "panic_fmt"]
#[lang = "eh_personality"] extern fn eh_personality() {}
#[no_mangle]
pub extern fn panic_fmt(fmt: core::fmt::Arguments, file: &'static str, line: u32) -> ! {
    println!("\n\nPANIC in {} at line {}:", file, line);
    println!("    {}", fmt);
    loop{}
}
```

Here is partialy my Cargo.toml :

```
[lib]
crate-type = ["staticlib"]

[dependencies]
multiboot2 = { version = "0.19", default-features = false }
rlibc = "1.0.0"
spin = "0.9.8"
volatile = "0.2.7"
x86_64 = "0.14.11"

[dependencies.lazy_static]
version = "1.4.0"
features = ["spin_no_std"]
```

and my target :

```
{
    "llvm-target": "x86_64-unknown-none",
    "data-layout": "e-m:e-i64:64-f80:128-n8:16:32:64-S128",
    "arch": "x86_64",
    "target-endian": "little",
    "target-pointer-width": "64",
    "target-c-int-width": "32",
    "os": "none",
    "executables": true,
    "linker-flavor": "ld.lld",
    "linker": "rust-lld",
    "panic-strategy": "abort",
    "disable-redzone": true,
    "features": "-mmx,-sse,+soft-float"
}
```

When compiling, I got the following error :
panic_fmt lead to found duplicate lang item `panic_fmt` the lang item is first defined in crate `core`

I can't figure out why

I tried to take a look on some issues from Rust official repository but nothing is really similar to my case.

Comment: Why do you want to implement `panic_fmt` language item though (and not just set the panic handler)? It's expected to be only in core, not to be overridden by anything.

Comment: But the real question is why I can't ? I would like to implement my own behaviour for this handler

Comment: There's support for overwriting the panic handler. There is no support for overwriting the `panic_fmt` function, which is _not_ a handler - it's just a function.

Comment: Well, it's possible to override (or, more precisely, to declare in the own code) the `panic_fmt`, since it's possible to go `#[no_core]`. But the only case where this is justified is probably when you _are_ `core`.